# Reputation indicator not working?

Tags: bug, reputation

The reputation activity flag at the top of the window doesn't seem to be working reliably lately. For example, I've gotten 11 upvotes on questions today, but the reputation activity indicator at the top of the window has remained gray all day. I only knew about the upvotes because I noticed that my rep score had increased and I checked the Reputation tab on my profile.

This seems to have been going on for 'a while' - maybe the past month?

Comment: Sometimes the indicators (rep count / +10 notifications) get out of sync. In my experience, it usually fixes itself after less than a day